# Canned Laughter SFX

Tags: laughter, library, sfx

Does anyone know of a decent Canned Laughter resource/library, preferably British/English and able to buy online and download?

I can only seem to find packs of sounds costing $200+ or expensive individual sounds, but I need something in between.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here are links to a couple of pages at rocksuresoundz.com that are laughter sfx. They are individual files, not packs though.
http://rocksuresoundz.com/store/ambiance/laughting/page/1/
http://rocksuresoundz.com/store/foley/laugh/page/1/

Answer (score 1):

I always try searching for creative commons stuff first.  This is the best I could find after a short search of CC0 licensed material.  https://www.freesound.org/people/urupin/sounds/122614/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there are any decent packs out there. But you can try this: http://www.soundsnap.com/search/audio/laughter/score
351 results and reasonable rates.

Answer (score -3):

There's a lot of great stuff you can capture from Spotify using Soundflower or another virtual jack of sorts. There's a number of royalty free stuff on the service if you search right.

Comment: It's gravely important to note that his is copyright infringement no matter how you slice it.  Royalty free is NOT public domain.  Royalty free only means that once you pay for the license up front, you don't report the usage, whereas needle-drop licensing (such as wit music) requires the reporting of cues for residuals purposes.  Hence, royalty (residuals) free.  You still must pay for the license.

Comment: Unless you purchase something on there as a download (a la iTunes) and it explicity says it's being licensed to the downloader/purchaser as a royalty free license, it's copywright infringement/IP theft to synchronize it to picture or use it in any other such esteem.

Comment: Err, thanks for the insight. I should have rather stated it as "that's your legal ground to tread."